# Improving the performance of reading blobs from a SQLite database

Tags: ios, database, multithreading, performance, sqlite

I have a SQLite database with small images stored as blobs. I need to read a few dozen of these images out as quickly as possible to display them in a user interface.

Profiling the code revealed that the vast majority of time is spent in the `sqlite3_step` call that reads from the database.

How can I improve the performance of these reads?

One idea is to have multiple threads reading from the database at the same time to improve performance, but [the threading documentation](https://www.sqlite.org/threadsafe.html) in SQLite is not very clear: is it possible to have multiple threads reading from the database at once, or will reads always be serialized, regardless of which thread they come from?

Are there other ways of improving the throughput of reading blobs from a SQLite database?

Comment: One idea is to not put large blobs into the database in the first place and to keep them in the filesystem and just keep a reference to them in the database.  The reason for this?  Performance.

Comment: @trojanfoe Agree, but that's not an option in this particular case.

Comment: Then I think you'll have to pay the price.  There are techniques to improve insert performance, however I don't believe there is much you can do about read performance.

Comment: Having said that, are you actually suffering from performance issues?  If you stored the images in the filesystem then you'd probably find most the time being spent in `read()`, but that's simply because it's the most expensive system call.  It doesn't necessarily mean you have a problem, however.

Comment: Why you are not using documents directory to save images ? you should have your images in document directory and you should just save it's name (i.e path) in sqlite database. so by that name you can quickly use it!

Comment: Show your database schema.

Answer (score 0):

It is possible, but not necessarily safe, to have multiple threads reading from an SQLite database at once, depending on your usage pattern.

If you use serialized mode, multiple threads won't help you since the requests won't execute in parallel.  The documentation implies that multithreaded mode would allow you to use multiple threads to read in parallel, but each thread would need to have its own database connection, so this might be the option to try; I suspect this works better if you are not also writing to the database.

It's also possible that the limiting factor for your application is the read speed of the disk, in which case there isn't any way for threads to help you, since they all access the same SQLite database file on the same disk.